# Rename a file if the file name between substrings if result is a number

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have some files that look something like this:

prtx010.prtx010.0199.785884.351.05042413

prtx010.prtx010.0199.123456.351.05042413

prtx010.prtx010.0199.122566.351.05042413

prtx010.prtx010.0199.this.351.05042413

prtx010.prtx010.0199.something.351.05042413

Now, I want to substring those files so that I get the following results

785884

123456

122566

(This is left 21 and right -12)

The thing is, I only want to substring those files between the stated positions only if they are numeric and 6 digits long.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this gratefully received.

At the moment, this is what I have, but it substrings all the files:

```
//Rename all files
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\prod\abc"); //location of files
DirectoryInfo di2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\prod\abc\");//where they are going
string lstrSearchPattern = "prtx010.prtx010.0199.";
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles(lstrSearchPattern + "*"))

{
    string newName = fi.Name.Substring(lstrSearchPattern.Length, 6);
    fi.MoveTo(di2 + newName);

    //do something with the results
}
di = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then `newName` will contain the six characters you're interested in. For example, it might contain `122566`, or it might contain `this.3`. You can use a regular expression to determine if it's numeric:

```
if (Regex.Matches(newName, @"^\d{6}$"))
{
    // The string is numeric.
}
```

Actually, that's not entirely true because the pattern after the period could be `123456abc`. What you're looking for is your prefix string, followed by a period, six digits, and another period. So what you want is:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"$prtx010\.prtx010\.0199\.(\d{6})\.)");
Match m = re.Match(fi.Name);
if (m.Success)
{
    // The string is 6 digits
    string newName = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jim and many thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I never thought about using regex and it makes perfect sense . . . . except I am not entirely sure how to use your example in my code to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @user2050866: I showed you how to reliably get the 6-digit string from the file name. I thought that's what you were asking for. If that's not what you're trying to do, then you need to provide a better explanation in your question.

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry. Your code is what I want to achieve . . . . my problem is that I am not sure how to make it work? That is, apply your code to my directory? Hope that makes a tad more sense?

Comment: @user2050866: what do you want to do with the `newName` once you have it? Are you trying to move only the files that match the pattern? Edit your question and give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, trying to move only the files that match the pattern. Once that has been achieved, I will be using MySqlBulkLoader to import them to my database.